Why does combining gluten-free and dairy-free substitutions make my Dutch baby recipe fail?
My family uses this recipe to make Dutch babies (we call it Dutch puffs, but my Internet searching found that's not the most common name):

4 eggs
1 cup flour
1 cup milk
Put some butter in a baking dish and preheat the dish in the oven.
Mix all ingredients in a blender until it's frothy with air.
Pour the mix into the preheated dish.
Bake at 375 degrees Fahrenheit for 25 minutes.

One of us has a bad gluten sensitivity, so we substituted the flour with Bob's Red Mill Gluten Free 1-to-1 Baking Flour. This works great.
I and some close relatives have issues with dairy, so we sometimes substitute the milk with Almond Breeze Unsweetened Original Almond Milk. This substitution, by itself, also works well.
However, we have tried several times to combine both substitutions to accommodate both dietary problems at the same time, and every time the combination resulted in an unappetizing soggy mush.
Why does this happen, and how can we fix it?

I suspect it's the gluten-free more than the dairy-free.  When you let a very wet batter sit, it forms gluten without kneeling... and you need it to trap the air when it does its popover thing.  This site says that the gums in gluten free flour blends are a problem: https://glutenfreeonashoestring.com/gluten-free-dutch-baby/

@Joe The issue is an interaction between them, somehow. Either substitution on its own works well. It's only the combination of both that causes a problem.

Have you tried different brands of your substitutions? I don't substitute dairy, but many of my gf recipes explicitly state that milk substitutes are possible. Also, anything based on a loose batter (pancakes, crepes, I suppose also Dutch babies) is generally easier to make gf than cakes or bread. So, I would expect the combination to work, and maybe you hit on some rare and unfortunate combination of products.

@Douglas quite a few plant based milks also use gums to try to match consistency.  You might try oat milk, which is more likely to have starches instead of gums, or canned coconut milk and thinning it yourself

If the "issues" with dairy are lactose intolerance, you might try substituting a lacose-free milk (eg the lactaid or fairlife brands are generally wide-spread and available where I am.) Of course if it's an allergy or religious restriction, this isn't a solution.

Mystery solved!
While googling about why my gluten-free cookies had a raw flour taste in them, I found several comments that Bob's Red Mill GF flour is not ground very finely, and the larger granules of rice flour in the mix can take a while to properly absorb their portion of moisture in the dough. One of the recommended solutions for that issue was to let the dough "rest" for a while, just leaving the bowl full of dough out on the counter and waiting before actually baking any of it.
I tried that with my Dutch Baby batter, and I just now finished eating a properly formed and tasty dairy-free gluten-free Dutch Baby.
I rested the batter for 2 hours this time, which is probably excessive. Some of the recommendations I found for cookie dough suggest 30 minutes. I'll test some shorter rest times in the future.
I guess normal milk gets absorbed by the rice flour faster for some reason.

Oh yes! Milling grade is indeed a common issue with gluten-free flours. I've even purchased something labelled "flour" which turned out to be coarse-semolina-sized (and because it was also whole grain, completely unusable as flour, only as polenta). So, good find, and thank you for reporting back!

I don't even know if it's solely the grind.  America's Test Kitchen had a gluten free baking book that said that non-wheat flours needed extra time to fully hydrate, so I assume it was something about the grains themselves (like how water passes through different types of clay at different rates)
